# How to replace vowels in a char array

Tags: java

I'm having trouble creating an array that will change the vowels in my array with what a user inputs. An issue that has come up is that when it asks for letter `i` I get an `inputmismatch`.

```
/******************************************************************************
 * This function will prompt the user to replace all vowels in the array
 ******************************************************************************/
public static void replace( char [] letters )
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(" Enter a character for i: ");
    int S = scan.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
    {
        if(letters[i] == 'A' || letters[i] == 'E' || letters[i] == 'I')
        {
            letters[i]= (char)S;
            System.out.print(letters);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you were posting your question (or indeed each of your six previous questions), there was a box to the right titled **How to Format**. Worth a read. Also avail yourself of the **[?]** link above the question text area. It is not okay to keep expecting other people to come in and format things for you.

Comment: And just below, there's a live preview of what you're typing. Don't post until this live preview shows perfect formatting.

Comment: Maybe `scanner.next(".")` -- The dot is a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that means "one character". More info at [Scanner's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()).

Answer (score 2):

printing an array is not the same as printing a primitave data type.  what you have

```
System.out.print(letters);
```

you can print the array by iterating through it

```
for(int k =0;k < letters.length;k++){   
    System.out.println(letters[k]);
}
```

also the scanner is asking the user for a number, it seems you really want them to enter a letter

Comment: certainly not memory location. There's no such thing in Java.

Comment: See [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(char[])) for an alternative

Comment: "memory location"? was this post modified? also, printing the contents of an array using a for loop works, but toString() is a convenience method that does it for you (actually it probably does exactly what you did).

Answer (score 1):

To read a single character from the input `Scanner` you can  simply use:

```
char s = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

or

```
char s = scan.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
```

if you just wish to consume a single character.

Comment: `next()` still consumes a full word.